# cin.getline() not get all character i input

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I am having a problem when I use `cin.getline()`.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input text:" << endl;
    char t[100];
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(t, 100);
    cout << t;
}
```

When I input:

> Hello.

It just shows:

> ello.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: What do you think `cin.ignore` does?

Comment: Also cstring is a char* based c-style string library, not std::string.

Answer (score 1):

You are [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)'ing the first character that the user enters:

> `basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );`
>
> Extracts **and discards** characters from the input stream until and including `delim`.

Simply get rid of that call, you don't need it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input text:" << endl;
    char t[100];
    cin.getline(t, 100);
    cout << t;
}
```

But, you really should consider using a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a `char[]` buffer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input text:" << endl;
    string t;
    getline(cin, t);
    cout << t;
}
```